# Linear or radial Gradient is not working(SVG Filter)

Tags: svg, filter, gradient

gradient is not working for the below code but when u remove any one child of "text-123-def" it works fine. Can someone tell me what's going wrong here? This problem happens in all browsers

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="text" width="500" height="780"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    style="z-index: 1;">
    <g style="opacity: 1;">
        <defs id="text-123-defs-container">
            <linearGradient id="text-123-filter-filler" x1="100%"
                y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="0%" gradientTransform="rotate(60)">
                <stop stop-color="rgba(24,130,208,1)" offset="0"></stop>
                <stop stop-color="rgba(14,194,203,1)" offset="100%"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <rect class="filter-bounding-rect" x="0" y="3.927999973297119" width="332"
                height="100.54227447509766"
                transform="translate(45.686516394138394 348.02223531474465) rotate(0 141.3324067502864 97.75946731604331) scale(1.261896488841843 1.261896488841843)"
                id="editor_s4JkKrLLLbm-TEXT1-main-filter0-grdnt-filter"
                fill="url(#text-123-filter-filler)"></rect>
            <filter id="text-123-filter" x="-0" y="-0" height="100%"
                width="100%" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <feImage xlink:href="#editor_s4JkKrLLLbm-TEXT1-main-filter0-grdnt-filter"
                    result="editor_s4JkKrLLLbm-TEXT1-main-filter0-grdnt-filter-img"></feImage>
                <feMerge result="editor_s4JkKrLLLbm-TEXT1-main-filter-merge-result">
                    <feMergeNode in="editor_s4JkKrLLLbm-TEXT1-main-filter0-grdnt-filter-img"></feMergeNode>
                </feMerge>
                <feComposite operator="atop" in="editor_s4JkKrLLLbm-TEXT1-main-filter-merge-result"
                    in2="SourceGraphic" result="editor_s4JkKrLLLbm-TEXT1-main-filter-FGPMerge"></feComposite>
            </filter>
            <g id="text-123-def" opacity="0.99"
                transform="translate(45.686516394138394 348.02223531474465)
                                    rotate(0 141.3324067502864 97.75946731604331)
                                    scale(1.261896488841843 1.261896488841843)"
                style="pointer-events: bounding-box;">
                <g id="text-123-def-span-0"
                    transform="translate(0 3.927999999999999)">
                        <g transform="translate(0 0)"> <!-- word 1 -->
                            <g transform="translate(0 0)">
                                <g transform="translate(0 44)">
                                    <path fill="rgba(60,63,29,1)" stroke="none" stroke-width="5"
                                        stroke-dasharray="0,0"
                                        d="M21.771-12.7305q1.9269999999999996 1.9884999999999984 1.9269999999999996 4.7764999999999995 0 2.3369999999999997-1.189 4.141-1.189 1.8039999999999998-3.4029999999999987 2.8084999999999996-2.214000000000002 1.0045000000000002-5.248000000000001 1.0045000000000002-1.107000000000001 0-1.886000000000001-0.041-2.6239999999999988-0.08199999999999999-5.1659999999999995-0.08199999999999999-3.362 0-5.084 0.123l-4.440892098500626e-16-0.82q1.476-0.08200000000000007 2.1525-0.32799999999999996 0.6765000000000003-0.246 0.9224999999999999-0.9430000000000003 0.24600000000000044-0.6969999999999996 0.24600000000000044-2.255l0-20.336q0-1.5579999999999998-0.24600000000000044-2.2550000000000026-0.24599999999999955-0.6969999999999992-0.9224999999999999-0.9429999999999978-0.6764999999999999-0.24600000000000222-2.1525-0.3279999999999994l0-0.8200000000000003q1.722 0.12299999999999756 5.002000000000001 0.12299999999999756l4.427999999999999-0.04100000000000037q0.7789999999999999-0.04099999999999682 1.763-0.04099999999999682 4.182000000000002 0 6.416499999999999 1.7629999999999981 2.2345000000000006 1.7630000000000017 2.2345000000000006 4.6739999999999995 0 2.378-1.4964999999999975 4.263999999999999-1.496500000000001 1.8860000000000028-4.735500000000002 2.870000000000001l0 0.08200000000000074q4.510000000000002 0.6150000000000002 6.437000000000001 2.6035000000000004m-11.787500000000001-15.1905q-0.6354999999999986 0.28699999999999903-0.8814999999999991 1.0249999999999986-0.24600000000000044 0.7379999999999995-0.24600000000000044 2.214000000000002l0 9.265999999999998 2.747 0q3.362 0 4.6945-1.8245000000000005 1.3324999999999996-1.8245000000000005 1.3324999999999996-4.858499999999999 0-3.0749999999999993-1.352999999999998-4.591999999999999-1.3530000000000015-1.5169999999999995-4.3870000000000005-1.5169999999999995-1.2710000000000008 0-1.9065000000000012 0.28699999999999903m9.6145 19.802999999999997q0-3.238999999999997-1.7424999999999997-4.919999999999998-1.7424999999999997-1.6809999999999992-5.5554999999999986-1.6809999999999992l-3.444000000000001 0 0 10.373q0 1.476 0.24600000000000044 2.173 0.24600000000000044 0.6970000000000001 0.8814999999999991 0.9635 0.6355000000000004 0.26650000000000007 1.9474999999999998 0.26650000000000007 7.667 0 7.667-7.175000000000001"
                                        vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <g transform="translate(26 0)">
                                <g transform="translate(-26 44)">
                                    <path fill="rgba(60,63,29,1)" stroke="none" stroke-width="5"
                                        stroke-dasharray="0,0"
                                        d="M49.001000000000005 0q-2.788000000000004-0.123-9.389000000000003-0.123-7.872 0-11.89 0.123l0-0.82q1.475999999999999-0.08200000000000007 2.1525-0.32799999999999996 0.6765000000000008-0.246 0.9224999999999994-0.9430000000000003 0.24599999999999866-0.6969999999999996 0.24599999999999866-2.255l0-20.336q0-1.5579999999999998-0.24599999999999866-2.2550000000000026-0.24599999999999866-0.6969999999999992-0.9224999999999994-0.9429999999999978-0.6765000000000008-0.24600000000000222-2.1525-0.3279999999999994l0-0.8200000000000003q4.018000000000001 0.12299999999999756 11.89 0.12299999999999756 6.026999999999994 0 8.568999999999996-0.12299999999999756-0.28699999999999903 2.7059999999999995-0.28699999999999903 4.837999999999997 0 1.5990000000000002 0.12299999999999756 2.5420000000000016l-0.9429999999999978 0q-0.28699999999999903-2.664999999999999-0.7379999999999995-3.956500000000002-0.4509999999999934-1.2914999999999992-1.516999999999996-1.8859999999999992-1.0660000000000025-0.5945-3.2390000000000043-0.5945l-3.4029999999999987 0q-1.475999999999999 0-2.1524999999999963 0.22550000000000026-0.6765000000000043 0.22550000000000026-0.9224999999999994 0.9224999999999994-0.24600000000000222 0.6970000000000027-0.24600000000000222 2.2550000000000026l0 9.675999999999998 2.705999999999996 0q1.4350000000000023 0 2.2139999999999986-0.676499999999999 0.7790000000000035-0.6765000000000025 1.045500000000004-1.599000000000002 0.2665000000000006-0.9224999999999994 0.4305000000000021-2.316499999999998l0.12299999999999756-0.8200000000000003 0.9429999999999978 0q-0.12299999999999756 1.7219999999999978-0.12299999999999756 3.853999999999999l0 1.968q0 2.0909999999999993 0.24600000000000222 5.822000000000001l-0.943000000000005 0q-0.04099999999999682-0.2870000000000008-0.2459999999999951-1.9885000000000002-0.2050000000000054-1.7015000000000011-1.1275000000000048-2.5625-0.9224999999999994-0.8610000000000007-2.5625-0.8610000000000007l-2.705999999999996 0 0 9.84q0 1.5580000000000003 0.24600000000000222 2.255 0.2459999999999951 0.6970000000000003 0.9224999999999994 0.9225000000000001 0.6764999999999972 0.22550000000000014 2.1524999999999963 0.22550000000000014l2.993000000000002 0q2.5420000000000016 0 3.8744999999999976-0.6765 1.332499999999996-0.6764999999999999 1.9475000000000051-2.173 0.6149999999999949-1.4964999999999997 0.9019999999999939-4.407499999999999l0.943000000000005 0q-0.12300000000000466 1.1069999999999993-0.12300000000000466 2.951999999999999 0 2.337 0.28700000000000614 5.248"
                                        vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <g transform="translate(51 0)">
                                <g transform="translate(-51 44)">
                                    <path fill="rgba(60,63,29,1)" stroke="none" stroke-width="5"
                                        stroke-dasharray="0,0"
                                        d="M64.3455-29.0895q1.045500000000004 0.38950000000000173 2.1525000000000034 1.1275000000000013 0.902000000000001 0.5739999999999981 1.3939999999999912 0.5739999999999981 0.3689999999999998 0 0.5740000000000123-0.43049999999999855 0.20499999999998408-0.43049999999999855 0.32799999999998875-1.3735l0.9429999999999978 0q-0.2049999999999983 2.378-0.2049999999999983 8.364l-0.9429999999999978 0q-0.2459999999999951-3.3210000000000015-1.906499999999994-5.596499999999999-1.660499999999999-2.275500000000001-4.817500000000003-2.275500000000001-2.2140000000000057 0-3.608000000000004 1.3324999999999996-1.3939999999999984 1.3324999999999996-1.3939999999999984 3.4235000000000007 0 1.5579999999999998 0.7175000000000011 2.7059999999999995 0.7175000000000011 1.1479999999999997 1.8245000000000005 1.968 1.1069999999999993 0.8200000000000003 3.1569999999999965 2.091000000000001l1.189 0.7379999999999995q2.5830000000000055 1.5989999999999984 4.079500000000003 2.8084999999999987 1.4964999999999975 1.2095000000000002 2.3984999999999985 2.7675 0.902000000000001 1.5579999999999998 0.902000000000001 3.649 0 3.7310000000000003-2.460000000000008 5.7605-2.4599999999999937 2.0294999999999996-6.231999999999992 2.0294999999999996-1.9679999999999964 1.1102230246251565e-16-3.218499999999999-0.4099999999999998-1.2505000000000024-0.41000000000000003-2.3984999999999985-1.107-0.902000000000001-0.574-1.3940000000000055-0.574-0.3689999999999998 0-0.5739999999999981 0.4304999999999999-0.2049999999999983 0.4305-0.32800000000000296 1.3735l-0.9429999999999978 5.551115123125783e-17q0.16400000000000148-2.255 0.16400000000000148-9.840000000000002l0.9429999999999978 0q0.28699999999999903 4.141000000000001 2.0500000000000043 6.724 1.7629999999999981 2.5830000000000006 5.411999999999999 2.5830000000000006 2.2139999999999986 0 3.7720000000000056-1.3735 1.5579999999999927-1.3735 1.5579999999999927-4.0794999999999995 0-2.2960000000000003-1.5374999999999943-3.8949999999999996-1.5375000000000085-1.5990000000000002-4.8585000000000065-3.6080000000000005-2.418999999999997-1.4760000000000009-3.9155000000000015-2.6240000000000006-1.4964999999999975-1.1479999999999997-2.4394999999999953-2.7674999999999983-0.943000000000005-1.6195000000000022-0.943000000000005-3.7925000000000004 0-3.443999999999999 2.2140000000000057-5.2684999999999995 2.2139999999999986-1.8245000000000005 5.494-1.8245000000000005 1.803999999999995 0 2.849499999999999 0.3894999999999982"
                                        vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <g transform="translate(73 0)">
                                <g transform="translate(-73 44)">
                                    <path fill="rgba(60,63,29,1)" stroke="none" stroke-width="5"
                                        stroke-dasharray="0,0"
                                        d="M96.985-23.78q0 2.0500000000000007 0.12300000000000466 3.362000000000002l-0.943000000000012 0q-0.32799999999998875-3.157-0.8199999999999932-4.6945000000000014-0.4919999999999902-1.5374999999999979-1.7219999999999942-2.254999999999999-1.230000000000004-0.7175000000000011-3.7720000000000056-0.7175000000000011l-2.2139999999999986 0 0 23.329q0 1.7220000000000004 0.32800000000000296 2.5010000000000003 0.32800000000000296 0.7789999999999999 1.1479999999999961 1.0659999999999998 0.8199999999999932 0.28700000000000003 2.664999999999992 0.3690000000000001l0 0.82q-2.131999999999991-0.123-6.026999999999987-0.123-4.1000000000000085 0-6.068000000000012 0.123l0-0.82q1.845000000000013-0.08200000000000007 2.6650000000000063-0.3690000000000001 0.8200000000000074-0.2869999999999999 1.1479999999999961-1.0659999999999998 0.32800000000000296-0.7789999999999999 0.32800000000000296-2.5010000000000003l0-23.329-2.2139999999999986 0q-2.5420000000000016 0-3.7720000000000056 0.7175000000000011-1.2299999999999898 0.7175000000000011-1.7219999999999942 2.254999999999999-0.49200000000000443 1.5375000000000014-0.8199999999999932 4.6945000000000014l-0.943000000000012 0q0.12300000000000466-1.3120000000000012 0.12300000000000466-3.362000000000002 0-2.3369999999999997-0.28700000000000614-5.2479999999999976 3.403000000000006 0.12299999999999756 11.562000000000012 0.12299999999999756 8.117999999999995 0 11.520999999999987-0.12299999999999756-0.28699999999999193 2.910999999999998-0.28699999999999193 5.2479999999999976"
                                        vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <rect x="0" y="0" width="98" height="54" stroke="none" fill="none"></rect>
                        </g>
                        <g transform="translate(108 0)"> <!-- word 2 -->
                            <g transform="translate(0 0)">
                                <g transform="translate(0 44)">
                                    <path fill="rgba(60,63,29,1)" stroke="none" stroke-width="5"
                                        stroke-dasharray="0,0"
                                        d="M12.177-28.208q-1.475999999999999 0.08199999999999719-2.1525 0.3279999999999994-0.676499999999999 0.24599999999999866-0.9224999999999994 0.9429999999999978-0.24600000000000044 0.6970000000000027-0.24600000000000044 2.2550000000000026l0 20.336q0 1.5580000000000003 0.24600000000000044 2.255 0.24600000000000044 0.6970000000000003 0.9224999999999994 0.9225000000000001 0.6765000000000008 0.22550000000000014 2.1525 0.22550000000000014l2.9930000000000003 0q2.542 0 3.8744999999999994-0.7175000000000001 1.3324999999999996-0.7175 1.9475000000000016-2.3164999999999996 0.6149999999999984-1.5990000000000002 0.9019999999999975-4.633l0.9430000000000014 0q-0.12300000000000111 1.270999999999999-0.12300000000000111 3.361999999999999 0 2.337 0.2870000000000026 5.248-2.7880000000000003-0.123-9.389000000000001-0.123-7.872 0-11.89 0.123l4.440892098500626e-16-0.82q1.476-0.08200000000000007 2.1525-0.32799999999999996 0.6765000000000003-0.246 0.9224999999999999-0.9430000000000003 0.24600000000000044-0.6969999999999996 0.24600000000000044-2.255l0-20.336q0-1.5579999999999998-0.24600000000000044-2.2550000000000026-0.24599999999999955-0.6969999999999992-0.9224999999999999-0.9429999999999978-0.6764999999999999-0.24600000000000222-2.1525-0.3279999999999994l0-0.8200000000000003q1.722 0.12299999999999756 5.247999999999999 0.12299999999999756 3.280000000000001 0 5.207000000000001-0.12299999999999756l0 0.8200000000000003"
                                        vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <g transform="translate(24 0)">
                                <g transform="translate(-24 44)">
                                    <path fill="rgba(60,63,29,1)" stroke="none" stroke-width="5"
                                        stroke-dasharray="0,0"
                                        d="M47.001000000000005 0q-2.788000000000004-0.123-9.389000000000003-0.123-7.872 0-11.89 0.123l0-0.82q1.475999999999999-0.08200000000000007 2.1525-0.32799999999999996 0.6765000000000008-0.246 0.9224999999999994-0.9430000000000003 0.24599999999999866-0.6969999999999996 0.24599999999999866-2.255l0-20.336q0-1.5579999999999998-0.24599999999999866-2.2550000000000026-0.24599999999999866-0.6969999999999992-0.9224999999999994-0.9429999999999978-0.6765000000000008-0.24600000000000222-2.1525-0.3279999999999994l0-0.8200000000000003q4.018000000000001 0.12299999999999756 11.89 0.12299999999999756 6.026999999999994 0 8.568999999999996-0.12299999999999756-0.28699999999999903 2.7059999999999995-0.28699999999999903 4.837999999999997 0 1.5990000000000002 0.12299999999999756 2.5420000000000016l-0.9429999999999978 0q-0.28699999999999903-2.664999999999999-0.7379999999999995-3.956500000000002-0.4509999999999934-1.2914999999999992-1.516999999999996-1.8859999999999992-1.0660000000000025-0.5945-3.2390000000000043-0.5945l-3.4029999999999987 0q-1.475999999999999 0-2.1524999999999963 0.22550000000000026-0.6765000000000043 0.22550000000000026-0.9224999999999994 0.9224999999999994-0.24600000000000222 0.6970000000000027-0.24600000000000222 2.2550000000000026l0 9.675999999999998 2.705999999999996 0q1.4350000000000023 0 2.2139999999999986-0.676499999999999 0.7790000000000035-0.6765000000000025 1.045500000000004-1.599000000000002 0.2665000000000006-0.9224999999999994 0.4305000000000021-2.316499999999998l0.12299999999999756-0.8200000000000003 0.9429999999999978 0q-0.12299999999999756 1.7219999999999978-0.12299999999999756 3.853999999999999l0 1.968q0 2.0909999999999993 0.24600000000000222 5.822000000000001l-0.943000000000005 0q-0.04099999999999682-0.2870000000000008-0.2459999999999951-1.9885000000000002-0.2050000000000054-1.7015000000000011-1.1275000000000048-2.5625-0.9224999999999994-0.8610000000000007-2.5625-0.8610000000000007l-2.705999999999996 0 0 9.84q0 1.5580000000000003 0.24600000000000222 2.255 0.2459999999999951 0.6970000000000003 0.9224999999999994 0.9225000000000001 0.6764999999999972 0.22550000000000014 2.1524999999999963 0.22550000000000014l2.993000000000002 0q2.5420000000000016 0 3.8744999999999976-0.6765 1.332499999999996-0.6764999999999999 1.9475000000000051-2.173 0.6149999999999949-1.4964999999999997 0.9019999999999939-4.407499999999999l0.943000000000005 0q-0.12300000000000466 1.1069999999999993-0.12300000000000466 2.951999999999999 0 2.337 0.28700000000000614 5.248"
                                        vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <g transform="translate(49 0)">
                                <g transform="translate(-49 44)">
                                    <path fill="rgba(60,63,29,1)" stroke="none" stroke-width="5"
                                        stroke-dasharray="0,0"
                                        d="M80.8365-27.88q-0.6765000000000043 0.24599999999999866-0.9224999999999994 0.9429999999999978-0.2459999999999951 0.6970000000000027-0.2459999999999951 2.2550000000000026l0 20.336q0 1.5580000000000003 0.2459999999999951 2.255 0.2459999999999951 0.6970000000000003 0.9224999999999994 0.9430000000000003 0.6765000000000043 0.24599999999999989 2.1525000000000034 0.32799999999999996l0 0.82q-1.8859999999999957-0.123-5.207000000000008-0.123-3.5259999999999962 0-5.248000000000005 0.123l0-0.82q1.4760000000000133-0.08200000000000007 2.1525000000000034-0.32799999999999996 0.6765000000000043-0.246 0.9225000000000136-0.9430000000000003 0.2459999999999951-0.6969999999999996 0.2459999999999951-2.255l0-21.976-9.881 26.526999999999997-0.6560000000000059 1.6930901125533637e-15-10.332-26.608999999999998 0 21.648q0 1.5990000000000002 0.2665000000000006 2.378 0.2665000000000006 0.7790000000000001 1.045500000000004 1.1275000000000002 0.7789999999999964 0.3484999999999999 2.418999999999997 0.4305l0 0.82q-1.475999999999999-0.123-4.182000000000002-0.123-2.4599999999999937 0-3.8129999999999953 0.123l0-0.82q1.4349999999999952-0.08200000000000007 2.131999999999998-0.4305 0.6970000000000027-0.34850000000000003 0.9429999999999978-1.148 0.24600000000000222-0.7995000000000001 0.24600000000000222-2.3575000000000004l0-19.926q0-1.5579999999999998-0.24600000000000222-2.2550000000000026-0.2459999999999951-0.6969999999999992-0.9224999999999994-0.9429999999999978-0.6764999999999972-0.24600000000000222-2.1524999999999963-0.3279999999999994l0-0.8200000000000003q1.3530000000000015 0.12299999999999756 3.8129999999999953 0.12299999999999756 2.132000000000005 0 3.4849999999999994-0.12299999999999756l9.019999999999996 23.738999999999997 8.815000000000012-23.616 1.9269999999999925 0q3.321000000000012 0 5.207000000000008-0.12299999999999756l0 0.8200000000000003q-1.475999999999999 0.08199999999999719-2.1525000000000034 0.3279999999999994"
                                        vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <g transform="translate(85 0)">
                                <g transform="translate(-85 44)">
                                    <path fill="rgba(60,63,29,1)" stroke="none" stroke-width="5"
                                        stroke-dasharray="0,0"
                                        d="M107.0375-27.839q2.9314999999999998 1.7629999999999981 4.551000000000002 5.104499999999998 1.6195000000000022 3.3415 1.6195000000000022 7.974500000000001 0 4.51-1.660499999999999 7.995-1.660499999999999 3.485-4.632999999999996 5.412-2.9724999999999966 1.9269999999999996-6.744500000000002 1.9269999999999996-3.894999999999996 1.1102230246251565e-16-6.826499999999996-1.763-2.9314999999999998-1.763-4.551000000000002-5.1045-1.6195000000000022-3.3415-1.6195000000000022-7.974500000000001 0-4.509999999999998 1.660499999999999-7.995000000000001 1.660499999999999-3.4849999999999994 4.632999999999996-5.411999999999999 2.9724999999999966-1.9269999999999996 6.744500000000002-1.9269999999999996 3.894999999999996 0 6.826499999999996 1.7630000000000017m-11.602999999999994 0.7994999999999983q-1.988500000000002 1.8245000000000005-3.075000000000003 5.104500000000002-1.086500000000001 3.2799999999999976-1.086500000000001 7.502999999999998 0 4.264000000000001 1.2095000000000056 7.503 1.2095000000000056 3.2390000000000003 3.2595000000000027 5.002000000000001 2.049999999999997 1.7629999999999997 4.591999999999999 1.7629999999999997 2.6239999999999952-8.326672684688674e-17 4.612499999999997-1.8245 1.988500000000002-1.8245000000000002 3.075000000000003-5.1045 1.086500000000001-3.2799999999999994 1.086500000000001-7.503 0-4.263999999999999-1.2095000000000056-7.503-1.2095000000000056-3.2390000000000008-3.2595000000000027-5.001999999999999-2.049999999999997-1.7630000000000017-4.591999999999999-1.7630000000000017-2.6239999999999952 0-4.612499999999997 1.8245000000000005"
                                        vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <g transform="translate(115 0)">
                                <g transform="translate(-115 44)">
                                    <path fill="rgba(60,63,29,1)" stroke="none" stroke-width="5"
                                        stroke-dasharray="0,0"
                                        d="M142.47-28.208q-1.4350000000000023 0.08199999999999719-2.132000000000005 0.43049999999999855-0.6970000000000027 0.34850000000000136-0.9429999999999836 1.1479999999999997-0.24600000000000932 0.7995000000000019-0.24600000000000932 2.3575000000000017l0 24.476999999999997-0.943000000000012 1.6930901125533637e-15-17.219999999999985-26.608999999999998 0 21.648q0 1.5990000000000002 0.2664999999999935 2.378 0.26650000000000773 0.7790000000000001 1.045500000000004 1.1275000000000002 0.7789999999999964 0.3484999999999999 2.418999999999997 0.4305l0 0.82q-1.475999999999999-0.123-4.182000000000002-0.123-2.4599999999999937 0-3.8130000000000024 0.123l0-0.82q1.4350000000000023-0.08200000000000007 2.132000000000005-0.4305 0.6970000000000027-0.34850000000000003 0.9429999999999978-1.148 0.24600000000000932-0.7995000000000001 0.24600000000000932-2.3575000000000004l0-19.926q0-1.5579999999999998-0.24600000000000932-2.2550000000000026-0.2459999999999951-0.6969999999999992-0.9224999999999994-0.9429999999999978-0.6765000000000043-0.24600000000000222-2.1525000000000034-0.3279999999999994l0-0.8200000000000003q1.3530000000000086 0.12299999999999756 3.8130000000000024 0.12299999999999756 1.8449999999999989 0 3.1980000000000075-0.12299999999999756l14.472999999999985 22.304 0-17.548q0-1.5990000000000002-0.2664999999999793-2.378-0.26650000000000773-0.7789999999999999-1.045500000000004-1.1275000000000013-0.7789999999999964-0.34850000000000136-2.419000000000011-0.43049999999999855l0-0.8200000000000003q1.475999999999999 0.12299999999999756 4.182000000000016 0.12299999999999756 2.4599999999999795 0 3.812999999999988-0.12299999999999756l0 0.8200000000000003"
                                        vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            
                            <rect x="108" y="0" width="224" height="54" stroke="none" fill="none"></rect>
                        </g>
                        <rect x="0" y="0" width="224" height="54" stroke="none" fill="none"></rect>
                </g>
                <g id="text-123-def-span-1"
                    transform="translate(0 50.47027233984239)">
                    
                    <g transform="translate(0 0)">
                        <g transform="translate(0 0)">
                            <g transform="translate(0 44)">
                                <path fill="rgba(60,63,29,1)" stroke="none" stroke-width="5"
                                    stroke-dasharray="0,0"
                                    d="M23.001 0q-2.7880000000000003-0.123-9.389000000000001-0.123-7.872 0-11.89 0.123l4.440892098500626e-16-0.82q1.476-0.08200000000000007 2.1525-0.32799999999999996 0.6765000000000003-0.246 0.9224999999999999-0.9430000000000003 0.24600000000000044-0.6969999999999996 0.24600000000000044-2.255l0-20.336q0-1.5579999999999998-0.24600000000000044-2.2550000000000026-0.24599999999999955-0.6969999999999992-0.9224999999999999-0.9429999999999978-0.6764999999999999-0.24600000000000222-2.1525-0.3279999999999994l0-0.8200000000000003q4.018000000000001 0.12299999999999756 11.89 0.12299999999999756 6.026999999999999 0 8.569-0.12299999999999756-0.2870000000000026 2.7059999999999995-0.2870000000000026 4.837999999999997 0 1.5990000000000002 0.12300000000000111 2.5420000000000016l-0.9429999999999978 0q-0.2870000000000026-2.664999999999999-0.7380000000000031-3.956500000000002-0.45099999999999696-1.2914999999999992-1.5169999999999995-1.8859999999999992-1.065999999999999-0.5945-3.238999999999999-0.5945l-3.4030000000000005 0q-1.475999999999999 0-2.1525 0.22550000000000026-0.676499999999999 0.22550000000000026-0.9224999999999994 0.9224999999999994-0.24600000000000044 0.6970000000000027-0.24600000000000044 2.2550000000000026l0 9.675999999999998 2.7059999999999995 0q1.4350000000000005 0 2.2140000000000004-0.676499999999999 0.7789999999999999-0.6765000000000025 1.0455000000000005-1.599000000000002 0.26649999999999885-0.9224999999999994 0.4305000000000003-2.316499999999998l0.12299999999999933-0.8200000000000003 0.9430000000000014 0q-0.12300000000000111 1.7219999999999978-0.12300000000000111 3.853999999999999l0 1.968q0 2.0909999999999993 0.24599999999999866 5.822000000000001l-0.9429999999999996 0q-0.04099999999999859-0.2870000000000008-0.24599999999999866-1.9885000000000002-0.20500000000000007-1.7015000000000011-1.1275000000000013-2.5625-0.9224999999999994-0.8610000000000007-2.5625-0.8610000000000007l-2.7059999999999995 0 0 9.84q0 1.5580000000000003 0.24600000000000044 2.255 0.24600000000000044 0.6970000000000003 0.9224999999999994 0.9225000000000001 0.6765000000000008 0.22550000000000014 2.1525 0.22550000000000014l2.9930000000000003 0q2.542 0 3.8744999999999994-0.6765 1.3324999999999996-0.6764999999999999 1.9475000000000016-2.173 0.6149999999999984-1.4964999999999997 0.9019999999999975-4.407499999999999l0.9430000000000014 0q-0.12300000000000111 1.1069999999999993-0.12300000000000111 2.951999999999999 0 2.337 0.2870000000000026 5.248"
                                    vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                        
                        <rect x="0" y="0" width="103" height="54" stroke="none" fill="none"></rect>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </defs>
        <g id="text-123" class="svg-element">
            <use href="#text-123-def"
                filter="url(#text-123-filter)"></use>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all when I strip out a child. I'd recommend stripping out all the transforms and styles and boiling this down to a simple test case - just the linearGradient, the rect, the filter and a single letter. It's very difficult to debug with all those nested transforms and long id names - all I can see immediately is that your feImage needs x/y/width/height, your feMerge isn't doing anything since all it has is a single child and your filterUnits(userSpaceUnits) doesn't match your filter dimensions (relative)